# Can javascript hold an object reference to a C++ library?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

I'm working on a full stack project and trying to keep a distinction between the View and the Model (MVC). the model is written in C++, and it will read data from a json file. originally I was using C++ to make the GUI and had the controller construct a Model object with the json file, then hold onto that reference. Then when getting data to give to the view, it would call methods from the Model object that was still within scope.

If the model object needs to be rebuilt all the time then id have to load in the json for every call, and that's way too slow.

Can a javascript controller (node.js?) hold onto that Model object and reference it when accessing the data? this is my first javascript project

Comment: Why does the model object need to be rebuilt all the time?

Comment: C++ and JavaScript treat the information they store inherently differently. JavaScript is an interpreted language, C++ is a low level compiled language. I don't think there even is a way to actually hold a raw memory address in JavaScript. Mixing up languages that are so fundamentally different is going to give you a real, real, REAL hard time, even if this wasn't your first project. I would suggest ditching the C++ and sticking with javascript only for this project for your own sanity.